# Must declare scalar variable in sql server dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having problems running sql server stored procedure. I using a dynamic sql.
I get the error "Must declare the scalar variable "@EmployeeId".

**SQL QUERY**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeaveDays] -- Add the parameters for the stored 
procedure here
@LeaveType varchar(5000), 
@AdminId int,
@EmployeeId int

AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
@queryString nvarchar(MAX);

SET @queryString = 'SELECT ' + @LeaveType + ' FROM CompulsoryLeave WHERE 
AdminId = @AdminId AND Id=(SELECT LeaveStructureId FROM Employee WHERE 
Id=@EmployeeId)';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @queryString,
    N'@AdminId int',
    N'@EmployeeId int',
     @AdminId = @AdminId,
     @EmployeeId=@EmployeeId

END
```

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) can't wait to get a hold of `@LeaveType`. You might want to validate it against the columns in the table unless you need something more interesting, e.g. expressions. If it is a list of columns then you can split it and validate them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sp_executesql parameter should be a single string with all parameter definitions. Try:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @queryString,
    N'@AdminId int, @EmployeeId int',
     @AdminId = @AdminId,
     @EmployeeId = @EmployeeId;
```

Comment: While you respect the order of the parameters, you can just pass the value directly without set it to the parameters as `... @AdminId, @EmployeeId;`

Comment: @Sami, it is true one can specify parameters by ordinal position rather than name with `sp_executesql` (and any stored procedure) but IMHO the named syntax is more maintainable, especially when the outer reference is named differently.